# how to get TextVIew,Description and image from Json Server

Tags: android, json

I have News_Fragment Tab with **ListView** Data got from Server,another Tab is Home_Fragment Tab.
in News_Fragment I have used java Classes like News_Adapter with RecyclerView,NewsResponse,NewsMainResponse & NewsTask
in this Home_Fragment Tab , I want display Title,Description and Image From Server
then How to i Display Title,Image and Description???

**This is News_Fragment data got from server in ListView**

[image]

**This is my Home_Fragment Screen**

[image]

Comment: How to fetch the image,Description,Title from server and show into the Home_Fragment android?

Answer (score 0):

Use android Volley Class
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Check this link out. This can be used for JSON and Images but not for large files.

Comment: just data present in Layout??then how??